# MySQL optimization on join tables with range criteria

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am going to join two tables by using a single position in one table to the range (represented by two columns) in another table.

However, the performance is too slow, which is about 20 mins.
I have tried adding the index on the table or changing the query. 
But the performance is still poor.

So, I am asking for optimization of the joining speed.

---

The following is the query to MySQL.

```
mysql> SELECT `inVar`.chrom, `inVar`.pos, `openChrom_K562`.score
    -> FROM `inVar`
    -> LEFT JOIN `openChrom_K562`
    -> ON (
    -> `inVar`.chrom=`openChrom_K562`.chrom AND
    -> `inVar`.pos BETWEEN `openChrom_K562`.chromStart AND `openChrom_K562`.chromEnd
    -> );
```

`inVar` and `openChrom_K562` are the tables I used.

`inVar` stores the single position in each row.

`openChrom_K562` stores the range information indicated by `chromStart` and `chromEnd`.

`inVar` contains 57902 rows and `openChrom_K562` has 137373 rows respectively.

---

Fields on the tables.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE inVar;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| chrom | varchar(31) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| pos   | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> DESCRIBE openChrom_K562;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| chrom      | varchar(31) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| chromStart | int(10)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| chromEnd   | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| score      | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

---

Index built in the tables

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM inVar;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| inVar |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | chrom       | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| inVar |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | pos         | A         |       57902 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM openChrom_K562;
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| openChrom_K562 |          1 | start_end   |            1 | chromStart  | A         |      137373 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| openChrom_K562 |          1 | start_end   |            2 | chromEnd    | A         |      137373 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| openChrom_K562 |          1 | chrom_only  |            1 | chrom       | A         |          22 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| openChrom_K562 |          1 | chrom_start |            1 | chrom       | A         |          22 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| openChrom_K562 |          1 | chrom_start |            2 | chromStart  | A         |      137373 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| openChrom_K562 |          1 | chrom_end   |            1 | chrom       | A         |          22 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| openChrom_K562 |          1 | chrom_end   |            2 | chromEnd    | A         |      137373 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

---

Execution plan on MySQL

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `inVar`.chrom, `inVar`.pos, score  FROM `inVar`  LEFT JOIN `openChrom_K562`  ON ( inVar.chrom=openChrom_K562.chrom AND  `inVar`.pos BETWEEN chromStart AND chromEnd );
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+--------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys                              | key        | key_len | ref             | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+--------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | inVar          | index | NULL                                       | PRIMARY    | 37      | NULL            | 57902 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | openChrom_K562 | ref   | start_end,chrom_only,chrom_start,chrom_end | chrom_only | 33      | tmp.inVar.chrom |  5973 |             |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+--------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
```

It seems it only optimizes by looking `chrom` in two tables. Then do the brute-force comparing in the tables.

Is there any ways to do the further optimization like indexing on the position?

*(It is my first time posting the question, sorry for the poor posting quality.)*

Comment: Does the query plan change at all if you put the BETWEEN section in a WHERE clause instead of having it be part of the ON clause? (I don't expect this will improve things but it seems worth checking out.)

Comment: @Ilion, I have tried, there is no different...

Answer (score 0):

`chrom_only` is likely to be a bad index selection for your join as you only have chrom 22 values.

If I have interpreted this right the query should be faster if using `start_end`

```
SELECT `inVar`.chrom, `inVar`.pos, `openChrom_K562`.score
FROM `inVar`
LEFT JOIN `openChrom_K562`
USE INDEX (`start_end`)
ON (
`inVar`.chrom=`openChrom_K562`.chrom AND
`inVar`.pos BETWEEN `openChrom_K562`.chromStart AND `openChrom_K562`.chromEnd
)
```

Comment: Thanks your reply.
Since the table join in range is really really poor...
I have already switch to another approach by building interval tree :P

Comment: @EricHo, using interval trees seems great, but is there a way to use them (with)in SQL? I've more or less a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27433474/559784).